# Dynamicly putting Object to many visual parents in WPF

Tags: wpf, dynamic, binding, controls

I want to create my own usercontrol which will take some FrameworkElement as parameter (as Content) and then it will didplay it on few copies (how much? it depends) Anyway copies has to be binded to their VM. Single copy will be probably a StackPanel with few binded buttons and TextBoxes. So it will look like this:

```
<MyControl> <Panel with stuff in it/> </MyControl>
```

Now in my control I hot ItemsControl and I am dynamicly putting there items. But one content (stack panel for example) can only has one parent so it doesn't work. How can I achive this? I heard that DataTemplates can help me but I don't know how. Also I wander if I can't do something like this:

```
<MyControl> <ViewModel of Panel with stuff/> </MyControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a `DataTemplate` property that contains the `FrameworkElement`(s), then create `ContentPresenter`s in the control, with their `Content` set to the piece of ViewModel and their `ContentTemplate` set to your `DataTemplate` property.